# Modification of the server http responses on the client site

Tags: windows, http, cross-browser, wfp

I want to modify all http responses (http pages): add some js into server responses before it will appears in browser.

For example "*Ad muncher*" is doing it. It add js that removes ad from all pages.

**How can I do it?**

I known only 1 solution: 
**WFP** (Windows Filtering Platform), but it is available only from windows vista.

***P.S: I don't want to use proxy server for this purpose.*** Because I want the cross-browser solution, I don't want to let user change any browser settings. Also user could work througth some other proxy...

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Komodia's Redirector[1](http://www.komodia.com/products/komodia-redirector/). It uses Winsock LSP. And it has WFP module for Windows 7 and 8.

Comment: Interesting, but it costs more than thousand $... Too much for me.